# Logic Pro X Play Engine Plugin not working

Tags: logic-pro

I recently purchased the student license subscription to the Composer Cloud for the East West orchestral libraries. I would like to use my newfound musical powers within Logic Pro X, but I seem unable to use them.

All of the (few) tips I have found have told me to select the desired instrument from the "Play" subsection of the "AU Instruments," but sadly the only things appearing therein is "Apple."

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on here. Help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Have you downloaded the Play software to your computer?

Comment: Logic scans for new plug ins each time it opens. If it has found a new plug in you’ll see it pause on a window telling you about this. Have you seen this?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

1. Go to Macintosh HD/Library/Audio/Plug-ins/Components.
2. If you can see your plugin in the list of Audio Units, select the file and move it to the Desktop.
3. Restart the Mac and start Logic Pro, then shut down Logic Pro and move the Audio Units which were moved to the desktop back into the HD/Library/Audio/Plug-ins/Components folder.
4. Restart Logic Pro and your plugin should now appear in the Audio Units list.

Comment: Hey! Figured it out :) Hope this helps:

1- Go to Macintosh HD/Library/Audio/Plug-ins/Components. 

2- If you can see your plugin in the list of Audio Units, select the file and move it to the Desktop. 

3- Restart the Mac and start Logic Pro, then shut down Logic Pro and move the Audio Units which were moved to the desktop back into the HD/Library/Audio/Plug-ins/Components folder. 

4- Restart Logic Pro and your plugin should now appear in the Audio Units list.